# Windows 7 domain network stuck in Public mode

Tags: windows-7, networking, google-chrome-extensions

Connecting my work laptop to wireless at work always disables my Chrome extensions.

After much research, I determined that even though this is a domain network at work, the network adapter was being locked into 'Public' mode, which apparently blocks Chrome extensions.

However, all attempts to change the network adapter to 'Private' mode failed.  even this [MS FixIt](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2578723) failed.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://evansblog.thebarrs.info/2013/02/windows-server-force-your-network.html) under the **Using Network Connection Properties**.

While performing this procedure, I noticed that the domain controller is pushing down multiple domain suffixes.  My guess is, because of this, the Microsoft Network Location Awareness was totally confused.

But which of the multiple domain suffix to use?

Using ***ipconfig*** in a terminal, I determined the correct domain suffix, and plugged that in as the suffix to use for this computer.  After Ok/Close'ing all the dialogs, the problem was fixed.